# Inline Font Awesome 5 Icon in SVG

Tags: svg, font-awesome

I have an svg button where I need to include the text + Upload. For the plus I would like to leverage the Font Awesome 5 plus icon. I'm using it inside a text tag and while it does render, it's showing as a solid font style by default. Is there a way to indicate which font set to use (light or regular)?

```
<text x="20" y="60" stroke="none" fill="#95A2AF" font-family="fontawesome" font-size="14px">&#xf067</text>
```